# Ember:SimpleAuth is undefined using ember-simple-auth

Tags: ember-simple-auth

I am a newbie to JaveScript and HTML. 
Looking at an existing code and struggling with below from quite some time now.
Below is the console output.
Getting the Uncaught error at below line in my code.

*App.CustomAuthenticator = Ember.SimpleAuth.Authenticators.Base.extend({*

The Ember.SimpleAuth is showing as undefined.

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js:3461

DEBUG: Ember             : 1.4.0 ember.js:3461

DEBUG: Ember Data        : 1.0.0-beta.7+canary.b45e23ba ember.js:3461

DEBUG: Handlebars        : 1.1.2 ember.js:3461

DEBUG: jQuery            : 1.9.1 ember.js:3461

DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth : 0.6.4 ember.js:3461

DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js:3461
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Authenticators' of undefined
```

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Ember Simple Auth now defines its own global `SimpleAuth` and doesn't attach to the `Ember` global anymore so you need to change your code to:

```
App.CustomAuthenticator = SimpleAuth.Authenticators.Base.extend({
  …
})
```